# UIButtons in UIScrollView is not touchable after rotate to landscape orientation using Storyboard and Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, landscape-portrait

I have a lot of "Buttons" in a **View** in a `ScrollView`, in a `SuperView`, of the `ViewController`.

```
ViewController
   View
      ScrollView
         View
            Button
            Button
            Button
            Button
            Button
            ....
```

I use `autolayout`, View to `ScrollView` (trailing, top, bot, lead 0, align x,y center)
same for `ScrollView` to `ViewController.View`.

when rotate to landscape mode, the screen only recognizes touches from **x 0 to 320**, any button after **x 320** is not touchable.

I did change the frame of the `SuperView`, `ScrollView` and Content View but did not do anything

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000,1000);
        _mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000,1000);
        _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000,1000);

        NSLog(@"size of self is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
        NSLog(@"size of scrollview is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(_scrollView.frame.size));
        NSLog(@"size of contentView is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(_contentView.frame.size));
        NSLog(@"size of MainView is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(_mainView.frame.size));

    } else {
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

As Matt suggested, I change the frame after the rotation (`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`). Here are the log of the frames of the views and one button not touchable

```
2014-04-29 18:08:27.528 [84526:60b] size of self is {{0, 0}, {568, 288}}
2014-04-29 18:08:27.529 [84526:60b] size of scroolview is {{0, 0}, {568, 336}}
2014-04-29 18:08:27.529 [84526:60b] size of content is {568, 466}
2014-04-29 18:08:27.529 [84526:60b] size of contentView is {{0, 0}, {568, 466}}
2014-04-29 18:08:27.530 [84526:60b] size of MainView is {{0, 0}, {568, 288}}
2014-04-29 18:08:27.530 [84526:60b] size of myBtn is {{364, 45}, {50, 50}}
```

So myBtn is inside the contentView yet it's not touchable?

Comment: Log on those sizes _after_ the rotation, not before, and see what it says. And log the frames of the buttons too. I'm betting that the buttons are no longer inside their superview. This is a frequent problem: a subview outside its superview is visible but not tappable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any constraint warning when you rotate the device?

I had the same issue, was able to see a pickerview but were not tappable when I rotate the device. after return to the previous orientation worked again.

In my case the solution was to remove all constraints (backup project first) and reset to suggested constraints.

Then It worked.

Hope it helps.

As interesting info: I'll tell you this started to happen, after I update XCode from 4.X to 5.0, so, probably something in the storyboard was not upgraded correctly.

Comment: I saw some autolayout error at launch. I fixed them, it's still having the problem. I tried reset to suggested contraints which mess up my UI but still didn't fix the problem.